# AbiWord - Top of the document blinks in Loki

Tags: applications, release-loki, hardware, display

Title says it all... When I have AbiWord opened in a document, the top of the document blinks. I've tried not having the app maximized, moving it to another monitor... no joy.

Since I've never used AbiWord, I don't know if this is a bug in the app or a problem with Loki or my hardware.

I'm using an Asus 1015E netbook, dual-core Celeron 847 @ 1.10 GHz with 2 GB RAM (although Loki only reports 1.3 GB; I don't know why). My second monitor is an Asus 22" monitor connected through the VGA port in the side of the netbook.

Any ideas, thoughts, or comments?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have an answer for your problem but i wonder...don't you have the problem with the black ruler in abiword? I installed in loki but so its not usable...[![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PlrBM.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PlrBM.png)

Comment: Actually this is more like a bug report than a question.